# Geb - no input for numbers 2 and 4

Tags: grails, selenium, geb

I wanted to test my webapp with Geb and Grails and come across a strange error. When I tried to enter numbers 2 or 4 into an input, these numbers are ignored and no number is entered. Other numbers work fine. This error occured when I used Chrome Driver, but when I switched to Firefox, it works ok. Does anybody have the same problem or know the solution? Thanks very much!

E.g.

```
def "test with numbers"(){
    $("input#someId\\.search") = "0123456789"
}
```

then in the input (text field), I have just 01356789.

Regards,
Lojza

Comment: Can you add some code examples? Does the same behavior happen if you stringify your numbers?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("yourSelector") << "0123456789"
```

Comment: Strange.  Doesn't seem to be a Geb issue then.  I know our team has run into issues with matching Chromedriver versions with Chrome versions.  Chromedriver 2 works well with chrome 29+, the older versions needed Chromedriver 26.  It might be that.